# How to call one specific method of Webservice from Client in Android

Tags: javascript, android, web-services, rest

I am stuck in calling this specific method:

```
public double[][] Multi(double a [][], double b[][]){
        return bimpl.Multi(a, b);
}
```

of my Webservice configured in my localhost. I need to send parameters from client and get the return value. I dont know how to make this call. I can succefully call the WSDL file of my webservice from android client.  Please help me to know how can I send a call to this method along with two parameters of type `Int` and then get the resulted value of `double [] []`.

Comment: You need to use an envelopment for consuming the web services. SOAP, at least... I´m using, just now, Retrofit for doing the call.
In the other hand, you need to send, from Web services, a serialized data, it use to be JSON, XML,...

Comment: Im using REST instead of Soap. I can call the WSDL file and can display it on my android device. Just need to call one specific method of many which will rturn the double value. Need to know the line of codes for it. Thanks

Comment: Is there any concept of XMLPullParser ?.. I saw a video they did it by XMLPullparser but It is not very clear to me.

Comment: As far As I Know. You can´t consume type of data Double directly from a Web services. You need to convert any kind of data which you want to sent from Web Services to Client in JSON, XML, or others,... Those are a different formats of String.
Are you using one of them? In which language are you implementing the web services?

Comment: Im using Java with  Intellij 15.0.2. We can receive data in plain form froma a WebService. The XML format is just needed to bring the data. How to convert that data to a Plain form.  see the Method. Im passing two int values as parameter and double [][] list should be the returned value,

Answer (score 2):

If using Java use `ArrayList<MyClass>` where MyClass is having two Integer variables.

Use Jersey for Restful webServices.

Comment: Please see the codes Im posted below and suggest what to add. need those specific lines to receive ArraList back to client. Thanks

Comment: package com.example.OffloadingTest;


public class Matrix {

    String result;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "your_services_name")
public class your_services_name {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "your_operation_name")
    public String descripcion(@WebParam(name = "your_int1") int your_int1, @WebParam(name = "your_int2") int your_int2) {
        // DO YOUR STUFF. CALL ANOTHER PRIVATE METHOD AND SO ON...
        String json = new Gson().toJson(your_value_to_returns);
        return json;
    }
}
```

From Client you have to call **your_services_name**, for after call **your_operation_name** (it is a method, so you will call it, passing your parameters... kind of: **your_operation_name(int1, int2)**). Your Web Services recieve the call (with the two parameters) and returns **your_value_to_returns**

Comment: Ohhh  thanks this may be helpfull.. I am going to try and will let you know about the result. I am very thankful for it :)

Comment: You´re wellcome. If my answer is working for you, remember to come back and reward my efford. Rate my answer. :)

Comment: Hey Bro, I got it upto some extent. :) Need you once more here please. Is XMLparser or Json parser necessary here to get array values in Plain_text instead of XML/Json format. Waiting to know please. See in your answer as you mentioned that it will return a Json object or in some cases it will return as xml response. My question is , how can we get the plain text from any of the above responses. To clearify more , I have developed a prototype in my android device where i will just enter two int value as matrix sizes to send as parameter to webservice. 1/2..

Comment: 2/2.. Now the service is going to return a resulted matrix in double[][]. If the above service return the resulted matrix in Json object or in XML form, how to convert it to plain actual matrix format in my android end? hope the question is clear to you this time :)

Comment: Hi Mushtaq. Before at all, If my answer worked for you. Please, reward my efford and rate it.
Flag my comments as well If you think they were useful...

Comment: Thanks Mushtaq... :). For sending data from Web Server to any kind of client (like android), you should use JSON format, XML is used less. In my code which I made for you, you can see the way to convert any kind of data to JSON: String json = new Gson().toJson(your_value_to_returns); Then you will send the String which name is json to any device, through the Web Services...
The idea is, once you programate the web services properly, you run this program for, later, consuming the JSONresult by another device. How consume this JSON by another device? I think that is another question...

Answer (score 0):

this is the Webservice Class.

```
package org.ali.javabrains;

import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import org.ali.javabrains.BusinessImpl.BusinessImpl;

@WebService
public class ProductCatalog {

BusinessImpl bimpl=new BusinessImpl();

public List<String> getProductCategories(String category){
    return bimpl.getProductCategories();
}

public List<String> getProduct(String category){
    return bimpl.getProduct(category);

}

public void RandomArray(int n) {

}

public void RandomArray1(int n) {

}
public double[][] Multi(double a [][], double b[][]){
    return bimpl.Multi(a, b);
}

}
```

and this one is the next class of webservice.

```
public class BusinessImpl {

double [][] a;
double [][] b;

public void RandomArray(int n) {
        double[][] randomMatrix = new double[n][n];
        double[] randomArray = new double[n];
        Random rand = new Random();
        rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                Integer r = rand.nextInt() % 100;
                randomMatrix[i][j] = Math.abs(r);
            }
        }
         a= randomMatrix;
    }

  public void RandomArray1(int n) {
        double[][] randomMatrix1 = new double[n][n];
        double[] randomArray = new double[n];
        Random rand = new Random();
        rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                Integer r = rand.nextInt() % 100;
                randomMatrix1[i][j] = Math.abs(r);
            }
        }
           b = randomMatrix1;

           Multi(a,b);
    }

  public double[][] Multi(double a [][], double b[][]){//a[m][n], b[n][p]
     if(a.length == 0) return new double[0][0];
     if(a[0].length != b.length) return null; //invalid dims

     int q = a[0].length;
     int m = a.length;
     int p = b[0].length;

     double ans[][] = new double[m][p];

     for(int i = 0;i < m;i++){
         for(int j = 0;j < p;j++){
             for(int k = 0;k < q;k++){
                 ans[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
             }
         }
     }

     return ans;
 }
}
```

I am done with Http Call. Its working fine. How to make call that webservice return the  arraList to android.

Comment: Mushtaq, you shouldn´t post updating information in an answer. For that you have to Edit your original question and add the information.

Comment: I can´t get it. Sorry. If your web services is working means you are passing the data to the client. So, you must to return an arraylist in your web services method. And you should pass it as a plain data (XML, JSON,...)

Comment: Hey :)  I am just talking about the connection. When I use to get a WSDL call and to display the xml file on my device, Its working fine. I need to get the plain text i.e the actual ArrayList values. How to call those values from client side. As you see the Multi() method of my Webservice need to return a Double [] [] value. How to make call from Client side to pass two Int paramters and then get this double [] [] Array. Hope it will be clear this time :)

Comment: Hehehhe. I think so. You want to know: How has to be your call to the Web services for passing two int parameters to it. Then, your web services recieve the called (two int parameters included) and it will return two double arrays... isn´t?

Comment: Nope. It will not .. :)  It will receive two int Parameter and then will return a double Array only. Please see my codes. You will understand. In  two of the methods I am passing two Int value of Matrix sizes then it generate two random matrices. Then it calls the Multi() method and pass the randomly genrated matrices as an Array. The Multi() method multiply both the matrices and return a single Array. How to call from Client device to get that Array. Thanks

Comment: My last shoot. I can´t get your code... When you´re saying that it is working, what do you mean? Even if your client is getting a XML file, it doesn´t mean that it is working. You need to check if the XML fiel contains the proper data inside.
By the other hand, when you are calling a Web Services, you should call a specific method inside it. I´m going to try to programm a demo to you. Check my answer below...

Comment: Brother EliasMP :) I told that when im not using to call the method with parameters. I disable the edittexts. Just run to get the XML and display it work. For getting the actuall AraayList i dunt know how to code. Thats my question

Comment: Hahaha. I surrender Mushtaq... I´m lost about your question. Good luck mate.... :)